# What are the various methods of hosting a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

What are the various methods of hosting a WCF service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four common ways, all of which are outlined nicely on MSDN: [Hosting WCF Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).

1. [Hosting in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx).
2. [Hosting in WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx).
3. [Hosting in a Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).
4. [Hosting in an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) (aka "self-hosting").

Comment: Hosting in a Windows service and hosting in an application is essentially the same thing, as a Windows service is just another application.

Comment: Sure, but they have enough different considerations that they are explicitly called out separately in MSDN.  Really, my answer is arranged exactly as MSDN lays it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

For right now, everything that's been said is correct.

- Hosting in IIS6 only support HTTP protocols and "on-demand" activation
- Hosting in IIS7 / WAS (only on Vista / Server 2008 and up) supports all protocols and "on-demand" activation
- Self-Hosting in a console app or Windows service supports all protocols, but doesn't support on-demand activation (e.g. your service must be up and running all the time, it cannot be magically activated when a request comes in)

What's not been mentioned is what the .NET 4.0 wave later this year (2009) will offer - there's a new add-on server component called **[Dublin](http://www.microsoft.com/net/Dublin.aspx)** which is said to offer a rich and managed hosting environment for both WCF services as well as WF workflows.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can host it in an IIS application or in your own executable. Typically the executable would be a windows service application.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that the 'typical' case for hosting a WCF service within an executable is via a Windows service.  WCF services provide an alternative to .NET Remoting for communicating across AppDomain boundaries.  As such, WCF is just as likely to be used within a Windows Forms application as it is a Windows service.

Comment: While you could certainly host a WCF service in a winforms app, I'm not sure many apps would do this. I think winforms apps would most likely be a WCF consumer and not necessarily a host. But then maybe I'm being short sighted and not envisioning a class of use casses that you have in mind.

Comment: As an example, if an application is extensible via plug-ins, it makes sense to load these plug-ins in their own AppDomain.  Once that is done, the application is now faced with the issue of bridging the AppDomain divide for communication purposes, a problem that WCF easily solves (as can .NET Remoting and inheriting from MarshalByRefObject).  I think in many cases, your assertion is correct; I just don't know that I go as far as saying it's 'typical'.  Sorry to quibble.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows process can be used to *host* a WCF service.  There are practically no restrictions on this - a process can host multiple WCF services and the same WCF service type can be hosted across multiple processes simultaneously.

From [Juval Lowy](http://www.idesign.net)'s book [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308), hosting can be provided by

- Microsoft Internet Information Server (IIS)
- Self-hosting within a Windows Forms application, Windows service, or console app
- Windows Activation Service (WAS)